# Custom UITableViewCell class not working (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So it has been a while since i have programmed in swift, and let me just say, it used to be a lot easier than it is now.

Anyways I have searched far and wide to look for an answer and still havent found one. I have a UITableView Controller that is in a container in a parent view controller. That table view controller is called RecentActivityTableViewController. My end goal is to change the text on the label contained in the UITableViewCell class. Everything is connected and the class has been set to the view controller

```
private let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
private let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

private var shifts = [Shift]()
private var clock = [Clock]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.register(RecentTableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "recentCell")
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    do {
        try shifts = context.fetch(Shift.fetchRequest())
        print("Loaded items in the substrate! ;)")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not load, error :(  \(error)")
    }

    do {
        try clock = context.fetch(Clock.fetchRequest())
        print("Loaded clock in!!!! ;)")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not load, error :( \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 1
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("running table")
    var cell: RecentTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recentCell", for: indexPath) as! RecentTableViewCell

    if cell == nil {
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "RecentTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "recentCell")
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recentCell") as? RecentTableViewCell

    }

    return cell
}

public func addShift(){

    if(!appDelegate.clockedIn || appDelegate.clockedIn == nil){
        let clocked = Clock(entity: Clock.entity(), insertInto: context)
        clocked.clockIn = Date()
        clocked.name = "Ethan Jamieson"
        self.appDelegate.saveContext()
    }
    else{
        let shift = Shift(entity: Shift.entity(), insertInto: context)
        shift.punchIn = self.clock[1].clockIn
        shift.punchOut = Date()
        shift.name = self.clock[1].name
        self.appDelegate.saveContext()
    }
}
```

And my custom cell view controller looks like this

```
class RecentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var test: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

The last time i remember how to change items in the cell was to pull that view controller up and change things within it. But when do this

```
cell.test.text = "custom text"
```

it does not load or show anything. It also will not pull up the label as if it doesn't exist. I am so confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the problems I can see:

In `viewDidLoad` your code should be:

```
self.tableView.register(RecentTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "recentCell")
```

In `cellForRowAt`:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recentCell", for: indexPath) as! RecentTableViewCell
cell.test.text = "custom text"
return cell
```

There's no reason to check if the cell is nil if it's not an optional.

Comment: its crashes at cell.test.text saying unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an optional value

Comment: What happens if you comment out that line?

Comment: everything works lol if i do. I just went ahead and started a new project with the same code this morning and now it works with no problem. Xcode used to be great, but now i find that I have to pull my hair out more often with it now.

Answer (score 0):

In `return cell` in `cellForRowAt`, change it to `return cell!`.